# Simulate enter on textarea with jquery event keydown not working

Tags: jquery, facebook, events, triggers, userscripts

I was trying to make facebook autoreply msg script, here is my code

```
$(window).load(function(){
var a=setInterval(function(){
var e = $('.titlebarText').html();
if(!e)
{
}
else
{
$('textarea.uiTextareaAutogrow.input').focus().val('Test!');
var c = jQuery.Event("keydown");
c.which = 13; 
$('textarea.uiTextareaAutogrow.input').trigger(c);
}
}
,5000);
});


$(window).load(function(){
var q=setInterval(function(){
$('.close').click()}
,6000);
});
```

Everything is working perfectly but simulating enter after focusing on textarea and inserting value..

Comment: @Tats_innit I don't think it's same..

Comment: Okies will remove it now `:)`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Simulating user input is bad and unnecessary generally. What's your expected result? Do you want to insert a line break or submit it automatically?

Comment: Is the textarea in a form? If so you could submit that form: `$('textarea.uiTextareaAutogrow.input').closest('form').submit();`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté submit it automatically, just like writing on chat. But i tested now and it wont trigger anyting, not just enter.. Don't know how to fix that..

Comment: +1 @nnnnnn, [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) is the way to go. (I'm checking if there's any form to be submitted in the facebook api)

Comment: @nnnnnn nice one, but it's submiting form which is posting on wall, and it's working, but not on chat..

Comment: Try with `textarea.uiTextareaAutogrow.MessagingComposerBody` for the chat (or just take out the `.input` class from the selector)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté without .input it's sending me to https://www.facebook.com/ajax/ufi/modify.php and first one is not working at all. looks like there is no form for chat, maybe

Comment: Yeah, I posted that after inspecting FB's markup. It's really messy to find anything useful, at this rate you'll most likely have to call the function which submits the chat message.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector looks strange.  `textarea.uiTextareaAutogrow.input` says "the textarea with class `uiTextareaAutogrow` and class `input`"--do you really have a `textarea` tag with the class `input`?

You could try this, provided your selector is correct:

```
var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 13 });
$('textarea.uiTextareaAutogrow.input').trigger(e);
```