# Change form value not working - keypress required - how to fire?

Tags: javascript

I like to fill out some forms in webpages automatically.
E.g. https://www.dropbox.com .
My problem:
The value is set but not used when sending the form.
Only if I use a real keypress the values are accepted and send.

Is that a kind to bot protection?

I am writting a Firefox Plugin that fills in my username and password.

In the picture you can see, using the script the values is in the background, the fieldname is still shown to me whereas using a real key press will enter the data correctly and allows to submit the input.
[image: jquery and keypress are failing: using my USB keyboard is working]

Thanks in Advance!

Minimal Code: https://pastebin.com/7TZyKaMM

Key press code seems to be equal to real key press but does not influance element value whereas `val('123')` updates the value but does not sending a keypress.

It is still not working :-(

The goal is: entering a text as value using key press simulation.

[image: Not working]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events  you could try to dispatch a logical event

Comment: Not working:  `elSource.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {key : "a", char : "a", shiftKey: false}));`, `$(elSource).focus().trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 68}));`, with `'keydown'` or `keycode: 68`. I don't know, why that all not working.

Comment: also not working: `$(elSource).val('123');
  $(elSource).change();`

Comment: Tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919459/using-jquery-to-listen-to-keydown-event , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-safari-using-javascript  - no success.

Comment: Not working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380634/simulate-enter-on-textarea-with-jquery-event-keydown-not-working and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically/44190874

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the answer:

```
 // set value
 $(elSource).val('123');
 $(elSource).change();

 // fire event
 var event = new Event('input', {
     bubbles: true,
     cancelable: true,
 });
 elSource.dispatchEvent(event);
```

https://pastebin.com/v1BmyGsE